# Need stacked column chart with multiple series

Tags: charts, highcharts, google-visualization

I have been stretching my head to get **stacked column chart with multiple series.** using google chart or highchart whatever is suitable.

I need to achieve the thing like below image:
[image: chart demo]

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped/

Answer (score 8):

One library that you can use to make this type of stacked column chart with multiple series is [ZingChart](https://www.zingchart.com).

Here's a fiddle of your chart with the ZingChart library:

```js
var myConfig = {
  "type": "bar",
  "labels": [{
    "background-color": "green",
    "x": "65%",
    "y": "23px",
    "height": "15px"
  }, {
    "text": "Win",
    "font-size": "20px",
    "x": "68%",
    "y": "15px"
  }, {
    "background-color": "red",
    "x": "82%",
    "y": "23px",
    "height": "15px"
  }, {
    "text": "Loss",
    "font-size": "20px",
    "x": "85%",
    "y": "15px"
  }],
  "stacked": true,
  "stack-type": "normal",
  "background-color": "#FFFFFF",
  "title": {
    "text": "Win Loss Report ",
    "font-family": "arial",
    "x": "40px",
    "y": "5px",
    "align": "left",
    "bold": false,
    "font-size": "16px",
    "font-color": "#000000",
    "background-color": "none"
  },
  "plot": {
    "-bar-width": "25px",
    "hover-state": {
      "visible": false
    }
  },
  "scale-x": {
    "values": [
      "JAN",
      "FEB",
      "MAR",
      "APR",
      "MAY",
      "JUN",
      "JUL",
      "AUG",
      "SEP"
    ],
    "line-color": "#7E7E7E",
    "tick": {
      "visible": false
    },
    "guide": {
      "visible": false
    },
    "item": {
      "font-family": "arial",
      "font-color": "#8B8B8B"
    }
  },
  "scale-y": {
    "values": "0:70000:10000",
    "short": true,
    "line-color": "#7E7E7E",
    "tick": {
      "visible": false
    },
    "guide": {
      "line-style": "solid"
    },
    "item": {
      "font-family": "arial",
      "font-color": "#8B8B8B"
    }
  },
  "series": [{
    "values": [
      15000,
      12000,
      42000,
      13000,
      19500,
      9750,
      11500,
      36500,
      11750
    ],
    "stack": 1,
    "background-color": "red"
  }, {
    "values": [
      13000,
      8000,
      5000,
      20000,
      17000,
      10000,
      34000,
      6000,
      5500
    ],
    "stack": 1,
    "background-color": "green"
  }, {
    "values": [
      13000,
      8000,
      5000,
      20000,
      17000,
      10000,
      34000,
      6000,
      5500
    ],
    "stack": 2,
    "background-color": "red"
  }, {
    "values": [
      15000,
      12000,
      42000,
      13000,
      19500,
      9750,
      11500,
      36500,
      11750
    ],
    "stack": 2,
    "background-color": "green"
  }, {
    "values": [
      8000,
      3000,
      9000,
      25000,
      12000,
      18000,
      37000,
      9900,
      8800
    ],
    "stack": 3,
    "background-color": "red"
  }, {
    "values": [
      11000,
      10000,
      32000,
      10000,
      10500,
      8250,
      9500,
      30500,
      9750
    ],
    "stack": 3,
    "background-color": "green"
  }, {
    "values": [
      23000,
      9000,
      6000,
      30000,
      27000,
      10000,
      44000,
      7000,
      6500
    ],
    "stack": 4,
    "background-color": "red"
  }, {
    "values": [
      12000,
      22000,
      52000,
      33000,
      29500,
      8750,
      12500,
      38500,
      21750
    ],
    "stack": 4,
    "background-color": "green"
  }],
  "tooltip": {
    "visible": false
  }
};

zingchart.render({
  id: 'myChart',
  data: myConfig,
  height: 400,
  width: 600
});
```

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id='myChart'></div>
  </body>
```

Basically, you would set up a stacked bar chart, and then add more sets of values. In each set of values, you would assign a stack number. Here are the docs for more detail: http://www.zingchart.com/docs/chart-types/bar/#bar__props_stacked_additional

Comment: Hey thanks for the zingchart. It covers almost my requirment. I just need to know one thing that in the screenshot provided by me contains the names below each column of chart i.e. 'a','b','c','d'. Does that thing can be integrated with it?

Comment: Yeah you might need to play with it a bit, but you'll need to modify the labels. Check out the docs: http://www.zingchart.com/docs/features/labels/ and the syntax library: http://www.zingchart.com/docs/json-attributes-syntax/graph-objects/labels/